# Is Inequality Transitive in Java?

Tags: java, equals, inequality, transitivity

If I have 3 objects **a**, **b**, and **c**, and I want to check that none of them are equal to each other, I need to check:

```
if (!a.equals(b) && !b.equals(c) && !a.equals(c)) { // to simplify, assume non-null
    // do something
}
```

According to the Java docs, for a correctly implemented equals method:

> **It is transitive: for any non-null reference values x, y, and z, if x.equals(y) returns true and y.equals(z) returns true, then x.equals(z) should return true.**

This states that equality is transitive, **but what about inequality**?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the language, but with the meaning of inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

given `a = 5; b = 6; c = 5`:

a != b -> true

b != c -> true

a != c -> false

so no, inequality is not transitive.

Answer (score 6):

It's not transitive.  Consider `x=1`, `y=2` and `z=1`.

Answer (score 3):

Inequality is never transitive (if you have 2 elements that are not equal, a and b). Because then you have !a.equals(b) and, because of symmetry !b.equals(a), but because of identitiy you have a.equals(a). So unequality cannot be transitive.

Answer (score 1):

No, of course not.

```
2 != 3
3 != 2
```

but

```
2 == 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, no. For transitivity you need the condition true for **any** x, y, z; but if I pick z == x, I would very much hope that

```
x != y
```

and
    y != z

does NOT then imply

```
x != z
```

since z **is** x!